# JSON to dict with JsonConvert

Tags: c#

I am accessing data from an API call in JSON format. I'm trying to put it in a dict, so that I can access the data. This works perfect for simple JSON objects, but fails for nested objects with "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: [. Path 'cluster_functions', line 1, position 539."

My JSON:

```
{
"id": "xxxxx",
"uuid": "xxxxx",
"cluster_incarnation_id": 151013752,
"cluster_functions": ["NDFS"],
"is_lts": true,
"num_nodes": 4,
"block_serials": ["17xxx"],
"ntp_servers": ["172.26.140.50", "ntp.xxx.be"],
"service_centers": [],
"http_proxies": [],
"rackable_units": [{
    "id": 23,
    "rackable_unit_uuid": "09f211d1-8fb4-xxxx-86e2-ce819xxxx29",
    "positions": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
    "nodes": [6, 7, 8, 9]
}],
"public_keys": [],
"smtp_server": null,
"hypervisor_types": ["kKvm"],
"cluster_redundancy_state": {
    "current_redundancy_factor": 2,
    "desired_redundancy_factor": 2,
    "redundancy_status": {
        "kCassandraPrepareDone": true,
        "kZookeeperPrepareDone": true
    }
}
}
```

The code:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpResponseStream))
                    {
                        //Response.Code = 1;
                        string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        consoleoutput("REST: result" + body);

                        resultdict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(body);



                    }
```

I am not sure how to continue. Should I parse line by line, and do another deserialize if the value isn't a string? But how do I do this if I don't know the format of the JSON upfront (and so the amount of levels).

Or is there a more efficient way to parse to a dict no matter the amount of layers?

Thanks

Comment: Not every value of those json properties are strings, so you can't deserialize this json into a string->string dictionary, try `Dictionary<string, JToken>` instead.

Comment: Ideally you should define a class with all those properties, but if you have to/want to stick with a dictionary, you need a TValue that can hold all the possibilities, string won't.

Comment: You could also just do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(...`

Comment: If the response is stable, you need to deserialize into some class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpResponseStream))
{
    //Response.Code = 1;
    string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    consoleoutput("REST: result" + body);

    resultdict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(body);
}
```

Anyway you shouldn't approach like that.

You should make a class describing every possible property and work like this:

```
public class Entity { /* properties definitions... */ }
```

And then

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpResponseStream))
{
    //Response.Code = 1;
    string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
    consoleoutput("REST: result" + body);

    List<Entity> entities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entity>(body).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how to work with property definitions, but I'll try to read myself into that. In the meantime I'm using the "string, dynamic" solution. However, then I am not able to access those nested objects. Should I be able to overcome this with the property definitions? Thanks!

Comment: You can directly access the nested objects even if the IDE doesn't suggest you their names, mark the answer as accepted if I helped you!